# How can I maintain control of the this keyword when extending prototypes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, prototype, oop, this, javascript

I'm implementing a class-like structure in jQuery, but I'm having some trouble when I try to call some of my functions.

This is how the structure is setup:

```
MyClass = function(name) {
    this.init(name);
}
$.extend(MyClass.prototype, {
    init: function(theName) {
        this.myFunction(); // works
        $('.myclass').each(function(){
            this.myFunction(); // doesn't work
        });
    },
    myFunction = function(){}
});
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to call one of my functions (e.g., `myFunction()`) from inside a jQuery block (like the `each()` construct above), I get the error "`myFunction() is not a function`."

I think this has something to do with the `this` keyword changing its meaning inside the jQuery block, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Bergi so this question is a duplicate of a question that was posted more than 4 years after it? Nice.

Comment: Yes, that question from 2013 is a canonical reference, explaining the problem that you also had and all (sic!) solutions to it extensively. Please don't feel offended, you've done nothing wrong :-) I'm just directing future readers to the canonical.

Comment: I'm not offended, and I definitely understand! ;) It just sucks that the copy around this feature makes it seem like the OP sloppily asked a question that already had an answer – "This question already has an answer here:" "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." Just a little weird.

Comment: Yeah, it really should say something like "*This question has a better answer here*" or so. See also [my MSO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285177/1048572)

Comment: Ah, very nice. Gave you a +1 over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign `this` to another variable, because of how scope works.

```
MyClass = function(name) {
    this.init(name);
}
$.extend(MyClass.prototype, {
    init: function(theName) {
        this.myFunction(); // works
        var that = this;
        $('.myclass').each(function(){
                this.myFunction(); // doesn't work
                that.myFunction(); // should work
        });
    },
    myFunction = function(){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass = function(name) {
    this.init(name);
}
$.extend(MyClass.prototype, {
    init: function(theName) {
        this.myFunction(); // works
        temp = this;
        $('.myclass').each(function(){
                temp.myFunction(); // works
        });
    },
    myFunction = function(){}
});
```

Try that. :)

Comment: You know .. your example says that `temp.myFunction();` doesn't work...

Comment: When I copied the OP's code, I forgot to remove the comment. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The `.each()` function changes the context of `this` (as does any function in JavaScript).

You need to do something like this:

```
MyClass = function(name) {
    this.init(name);
}
$.extend(MyClass.prototype, {
    init: function(theName) {
        this.myFunction(); // works
        var myClass = this;
        $('.myclass').each(function(){
                myClass.myFunction(); // doesn't work
        });
    },
    myFunction = function(){}
});
```

Comment: You know .. your example says that `myClass.myFunction();` doesn't work...